# pandas: condition with different index

Tags: python, pandas

As if statements and loops are very slow and difficult for pandas to compute, I'm trying to think how to rewrite the condition that I want to establish.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9]
df['y'] = [1.7, 1.8, 0.7, 1.4]
print(df)

     x    y
0  1.2  1.7
1  1.5  1.8
2  1.7  0.7
3  1.9  7.0
```

What I want to do is to make a condition that verifies if `df.y` will ever be less than `df.x` and if that is true then create a new column with the subtraction of the two index.

For example,

`df.y[0] < df.x[0]` if not,

then check `if df.y[0] < df.x[1]` if that is true then `df.new[0] = 1 - 0;`

And move to the next value: `df.y[1] < df.x[1]`

if not, then check `if df.y[1] < df.x[2]` if that is true then `df.new[1] = 2 - 1`.

If the value of `df.y[i]` is always greater than any `df.x[n]` value, then append as `False` to `df.new[i]`.

the output in this case should be like this

```
     x    y    new
0  1.2  1.7      3
1  1.5  1.8      2
2  1.7  0.7      0
3  1.9  7.0  False
```

in which `df.new` is the difference between the index of `df.x` with the index of `df.y` that we are trying to prove if will ever be lower than `df.x`

df.new could mean whatever the index is, if the index is the time df.new means the first time in which `df.y` will be lower that `df.x`.

Comment: can you post what your desired output df looks like also what does `df.new[0] = 1 - 0` mean here? do you mean `df.new[0] = df.x[1] - df.y[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works but this really is a loop as it uses `apply`:

```
In [225]:
def func(x):
    if (x['y'] > df['x']).all():
        return False
    else:
        return (x['y'] > df['x']).idxmin()
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
df

Out[225]:
     x    y    new
0  1.2  1.7      2
1  1.5  1.8      3
2  1.7  0.7      0
3  1.9  7.0  False
```

Comment: That's correct `apply` will not scale well, one thing you could do is assuming that all values are not unique you could create a dict of the unique values as keys and the row position values as the values and merge this, this should perform slightly better, your issue here is that you are trying to compare a scalar against the entire df for every row value, there isn't a built in method for doing this so you have to call `apply` here